# LINQ check for duplicates in nested collection

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

I have a collection `Col1` and each one of those has a collection `Col2`.

I want to know if any `Col2` have duplicate `Value`, and only when `Col2.Type= "AType"`.

```
Col1    Col2    Type    Value
Col1a   Col2a   AType   10
Col1a   Col2b   BType   10
Col1a   Col2c   AType   15
Col1b   Col2a   AType   10
Col1b   Col2b   Ctype   20
Col1b   Col2c   Atype   30
```

^ Would return `false`, there are no duplicates in Col2 for AType

```
Col1    Col2    Type    Value
Col1a   Col2a   AType   10 << Dupe
Col1a   Col2b   BType   15
Col1a   Col2c   AType   10 << Dupe
Col1b   Col2a   AType   10
Col1b   Col2b   Ctype   20
Col1b   Col2c   Atype   30
```

^ Would return `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool anyDups = Col1
    .Any(c1 => c1.Col2
        .Where(c2 => c2.Type == "AType")
        .GroupBy(c2 => c2.Value)
        .Any(g => g.Count() > 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var result = list.Where(a=>a.Type =="AType").
            GroupBy(p => p.Type).Select(group => group.First());
```

Comment: How would this filter out `Type = "AType"`?

Comment: @JanineRawnsley: Didn't saw it. Updated now

Comment: This seems unlikely to return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do something like

```
var correctTypeValues = Col1.Where(c => c.Type= "AType").Select(c => c.Value);
if(correctTypeValues.Count() == correctTypeValues.Distinct().Count())
{
  // no dups
}
```

Based in an IsUnique() Extension Method though:

```
if(Col1.Where(c => c.Type= "AType").Select(c => c.Value).IsUnique())
{
  // no dups
}
```